# Не получаеться установить pyinstaller

Tags: python

когда я пишу pip install pyinstaller выдает ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в pip. Попробуйте сделать данные действия:
pip install pip==18.1
pip install pyinstaller